# Vite and Heatmap React Refused to execute script from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, heatmap, vite

I'm on a React app created with Vite. I need to use the Heatmap libraries on Leaflet which I load like this on the index.html file:

```
<script src="/src/heatmap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/src/leaflet-heatmap.js"></script>
```

Locally it runs ok, I can see the heatmap and everything. The issue is on the Cloudflare deploy, I get this error:

*Refused to execute script from 'https://logistic.innercore.ai/src/heatmap.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.*

You can even see it for yourself going to https://logistic.innercore.ai/zones and picking the 3rd option on the bottom bar.
[image]

This issue really goes beyond my knowledge, I don't know what else to try.
Is it possible to add those javascript modules some other way? Or what would be the solution.
Thanks.